# How to Call a Stored Procedure within a Stored Procedure in MySQL

Tags: mysql, call, procedure

I want to use procedure like this, but this is not working.

```
SELECT s.* FROM (CALL SPLIT_STRING('a,b,c',',')) AS s;
```

Comment: You need function not procedure.

Comment: It is not possible. You can return dataset from stored procedure, but you cannot use it in FROM clause.

Comment: FYI, questions are greatly improved when you include the error message(s) you receive. If nothing else, it'll help someone in the future who is scratching his/her head over the error.

Answer (score 0):

What you mean is this:

```
select s.* FROM (SPLIT_STRING('a,b,c',',')) as s;
```

Comment: your sp not return Table Result set.